# Reclaim Database Wasted Space

Tags: oracle, performance, index, oracle-11g-r2

In our company we have a test server on which Oracle RDBMS 11g is installed.
My question is related to reclaiming wasted space.

I ran the following query:

```
select 
   table_name,round((blocks*8),2) "size (kb)" , 
   round((num_rows*avg_row_len/1024),2) "actual_data (kb)",
   (round((blocks*8),2) - round((num_rows*avg_row_len/1024),2)) "wasted_space (kb)"
from 
   dba_tables
where 
   (round((blocks*8),2) > round((num_rows*avg_row_len/1024),2))
order by 4 desc;
```

...which shows me the total wasted space for each table. So we have approx. 84 GB of wasted space overall in our database.

I want to know how to reclaim this wasted space without being able to use Enterprise Manager, because I don't have access to EM.

I have also noticed that the indexes on the database were last rebuilt in 2010. Could rebuilding the indexes solve the wasted space problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is all covered [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm#ADMIN10161), but basically:

- Enable row movement for each table using `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;`
- Shrink the object (`TABLE`/`MATERIALISED VIEW`/etc) with `ALTER <object type> <object name> SHRINK SPACE;`
- Resize the tablespace datafiles with `ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/path/to/your/datafile.dbf' RESIZE 500M;`

[Tim Hall](https://twitter.com/oraclebase) covers this in great length, with every conceivable option, in [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space) - a great resource.

Comment: I have so many tables and also list of datafiles which needs to be shrink, It will be time consuming. So is there any other way through which i can shrink whole database?

Comment: Script it by generating the DDL with a query.